# How to use scala and read file from Azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm trying to use the below Scala code to read a csv file from Azure blob storage.

```
val containerName = "azsqlshackcontainer"
val storageAccountName = "cloudshell162958911"
val sas = "?sv=2021-06-08&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiyx&se=2022-11-16T17:11:59Z&st=2022-11-16T09:11:59Z&spr=https&sig=ZAy5PeZu5jbICr5B%2BFTLLn6C5TMBxrU5WmbLCRfzNu8%3D"
val config = "fs.azure.sas." + containerName+ "." + storageAccountName + ".blob.core.windows.net"

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://azsqlshackcontainer@cloudshell162958911.blob.core.windows.net/FoodSales.csv",
  mountPoint = "/mnt/myfile",
  extraConfigs = Map(config -> sas))
```

When I run this code, I get below error.

[image]

The container name, storage account name and file names are correct.

[image]

I replicated the steps given here: https://www.sqlshack.com/accessing-azure-blob-storage-from-azure-databricks/

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I am able to do it using Python, but the scala code is not working

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this alternative approach with access key, I tried to reproduce it in my environment and I got the below results:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
  mountPoint = "/mnt/<mount_name>",
  extraConfigs = Map("fs.azure.account.key.<<Your_storage_account_name>>.blob.core.windows.net" -> "<< Access_key>>"))
```

[image]

Now, You can check. I can read CSV data with a mount path.

```
%scala

val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("Header","true").load("/mnt/dsff")
display(df1)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to replicate, but get the below error:


IOException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: 
Caused by: AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: 
Caused by: Throwable: 
Caused by: Throwable: cloudshell1425009348.blob.core.windows.net
Command took 5.83 minutes -- by arun at 11/16/2022, 10:36:39 PM on MyCluster

Comment: hi @Arun, try to replace SAS with [access key](https://i.imgur.com/KAbBOdW.png) and Please check above approach. it's working fine for me.

Comment: and check your storage account syntax: `wasbs://<container>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/`